# looking for proper hashtag wildcard syntax

Tags: jquery, hashtag

So let's say you have a bunch of similarly-named hashtags, as in, '#ola-ola-one', '#ola-ola-two', '#ola-ola-three', etc.

If I want to target all hashtags starting with '#ola-ola-' what is the right wildcard syntax structure to use?

Non-working example:

```
if (window.location.hash === '#ola-ola-(*)') {
    // just do it
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `if (window.location.hash.indexOf('#ola-ola-') === 0) { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
if (/^#ola-ola-./.test(window.location.hash)) {
```

Further reading:

- [Regular Expressions (MDN article)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [`.test()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)